# Laravel 5 Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I can't seem to connect to the database. Here's my configuration

- Mac OSX El Capitan
- MAMP Pro

I always get the error **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused**.
I have **my_users** table in the database **application**. By the way I am following this tutorial in youtube. [Link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3PsPHqYRfQ&index=6&list=PL_UnIDIwT95PiPV641VBnEwFAvswNZKuX)

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=LVwc8N06OepmCfptIcATzNxN2pkYJJwf

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=application   
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**my_users.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class my_users extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

use App\my_users;

Route::get('/', function () {

    $users = my_users::all();

});
```

**database.php**

```
return [



    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,


    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),



    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => database_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],


    'migrations' => 'migrations',


    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: `config/database.php`?

Comment: Is the name of your model.php is my_users also?

Comment: @aldrin27 **my_users.php** is the model

Comment: @tkausl OP updated. Please check :)

Comment: @ClydeScope Looks like the app can't connect to the DB. Try changing the connection details in `database.php` to the correct credentials for your DB. This is just to test and you shouldn't leave it this way. Let us know if it works.

Comment: @odannyc I tried that now it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in the `.env` file

Comment: @AlexAndrei now it says "Connection refused"

Comment: what's the name of your database?

Comment: @aldrin27 it's **application** which I set in the .env file

Comment: I mean the database table you used. For example in mysql.